# How to access Trac server (running Tracd) with computer name instead of IP address

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, trac

I am running Trac using Tracd as the interface. I can access the server by way of IP address (http://x.x.x.x:8000), but I want to access this by way of the computer name (http://compName) how would I go about this? I'd prefer to not have to use Apache as the web server.

All the machines involved are Windows machine's and in Active Directory. The Trac repository is on Windows Server 2003 VM.

Comment: Can you not access the computer by name in general or only for trac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can start tracd on port 80:

`tracd -p 80 [your tracd parameters]`

As far as the computer name itself goes, I can't tell from your question if you are having any problems contacting that machine by name. If so, here are the options:

1. Add a DNS entry to for that machine to your DNS server
2. Use the machine's NETBIOS name
3. Add an entry into your hosts file for it

Answer (score 1):

Stupid easy (but not *right*) way -- run on port 80.